# Create/Display DataGrid from a table (database) C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagrid, windows-mobile

I'm trying show a DataGrid in C# (for app WindowsMobile). I have a database ("pruebaDB.sdf") in DataConnections and one table ("tablaMercancia").

Also in DataSource I have "pruebaDBDataSet" and "tablaMercancia".

How I can show data table in a DataGrid?

I use a SmartDevice project (I can't to use DataGridView, only I use DataGrid).

I can show a new table (created for code) in a DataGrid, but I don't know to show an existing table in my database.

```
string conSTR = "Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)) + "\\pruebaDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";

SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);

string sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaMercancia";
connection.Open();

SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);

//...............
//...Any idea?
//...............

connection.Close();
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, Change Datagridview name as per below :

```
    string conSTR = "Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)) + "\\pruebaDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";

    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(conSTR);

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaMercancia";
    connection.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);


    //datagridview1 is name of datagridview in form:
    datagridview1.DataSource=ds.Tables[0];

    connection.Close();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it isn't OK.  I put: dataGrid1.DataSource = da.Tables[0];         but (ERROR)'SqlCeDataAdapter' does not contain a definition for 'Tables'

Comment: And I use DataGrid (no DataGridView) sorry

Comment: Please, Try with new code, is updated with Dataset and Fill by DataAdapter

Comment: Sorry, ERROR:  The specified table does not exist. [ tablaMercancia ].  I have this table in ServerExplorer ->  DataConnections -> pruebaDB.sdf  and  in DataSources -> tablaMercancia. Any idea? Thanks!!!

Comment: Please, change DS to ds and also check it whether datatable is in dataset or not?

Comment: Yes, I change DS to ds. Yes, this table is in database and in DataSource pruebaDBDataSet and query SQL "SELECT * FROM tablaMercancia" is OK. Sorry :( Thanks!

Comment: Your code is OK!!! Thanks!!! I am trying with other table and is OK!!! I belive my table "tablaMercancia" isn't good in dataSet...Sorry!!! And thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM tablaMercancia";
connection.Open();
//SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection);
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, connection);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Sorry, ERROR: The specified table does not exist. [ tablaMercancia ].

Comment: Try with Dataset instead of Datatable?

Comment: Like, sorry. See answers by @vikram jain.

Comment: See edit. You don't need a sqlcecommand object here. Pass your sql and connection to the Sqlcedataadapter.

Answer (score 0):

designing page track the gridview or data grid

1st use namespace `using System.Data,SqlClient;`

```
sqlconnection con=new sqlconnection("string path");
con.open();
sqldataadapter da=new sqldataadapter("select * from emp",con);
dataset ds=new dataset();
da.fill(ds,"emp");
gridview1.datasource=ds;
gridview1.databind();
```